# How to name a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data as follows in a `DataFrame` `symbolData`:

```
              Open      High       Low   Close      Volume  Ex-Dividend  Split Ratio   Adj. Open   Adj. High    Adj. Low  Adj. Close  Adj. Volume
Date
1980-12-12   28.75   28.8700   28.7500   28.75   2093900.0          0.0          1.0    0.424421    0.426193    0.424421    0.424421  117258400.0
```

When I get just the `series` with the `Adj Close` column, I would like to give it a name:

```
adjClose = symbolData.ix[:,10]
```

Right now, the above looks like

```
Date
1980-12-12      0.424421
```

I would like it to look like

```
                AlgoClose
Date                   
1980-12-12      0.424421
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
adjClose = symbolData.ix[:,10].rename("AlgoClose")
adjClose =pd.DataFrame(adjClose)
```

Answer (score 5):

after you define your series with `ix`, you can set its name with:

```
adjClose.name = 'adjClose'
```

or, you could keep the original column-name when you define the series, like this:

```
adjClose = symbolData['Adj. Close']
```

this 'named series' won't display quite how you asked for though, it will display like:

```
Date
1980-12-12      0.424421
Name: adjclose, dtype: float64
```

if it's more important to display as you want, rather than to keep it a series, than convert it to a one-column `DataFrame` like in Miriam's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can rename the Series and then use .to_frame to convert it to a dataframe. Also, it's better to use iloc instead of ix as it's going to be deprecated in the future.

```
df.iloc[:,10].rename('AlgoClose').to_frame()
Out[20]: 
            AlgoClose
Date                 
1980-12-12   0.424421
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `to_frame` method with the `name` parameter:

```
symbolData.ix[:,10].to_frame(name='AlgoClose')
```